# Pushing JavaDoc via Gitlab

Tags: java, gitlab, javadoc, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm working on a GitLab project, where I use the GitLab Runner to create JavaDoc using Maven. The creation itself works, but the Runner creates the files in it's own repository.

Is there any way, the Runner pushes the documentation on GitLab directly?

Thanks